# how to check length of string using tmap in Talend

Tags: string, boolean, talend, tmap

I am trying to check the length of a string using `mystring.length()` in tmap component of Talend. However, I am encountering an error

```
Type mismatch: cannot convert from boolean to String.
```

The fields:

```
Input port: string 50
output port: integer 50
syntax used: COLUMN_NAME.length()
```

[image]

Comment: I suspect this could be connected to another part of the code. Do you see an error when you click on the Code tab unterneath the design window?

Comment: I tried to rebuild the tmap and it ran successfully. I am not sure how it got resolved though. Thank you for your inputs!

Comment: I think this error is due to, joining CAMPAIGN_NAME( which is 'string') to other field(may be the data type of that field is 'BOOLEAN') which is not shown in figure...

Comment: May me due to some other mapping